# Validating SQL for backward compatibility - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, compatibility

Is there a way in SSMS to validate SQL code will work with older databases? Our development staff is on SQL Server 2017. We have a client who still runs 2012. It would be nice to know if any of our code will fail before deploying on the client. 
Setting the compatibility level on the development server has no effect.

Comment: Set compatibility level on DB level

Comment: Setting the compatibility level has no effect. Newer functions such as "Drop View If Exists..." still compile fine when compatibility is set to 2008 (100)

Comment: Applying procedure for example doesn't validate most of the stuff in the procedure. I think you have to build a custom validator for this - a unit test (using tsqlt.org)